# Why is there no tkinter distribution found?

Tags: python, tkinter, module

I am having a problem during the installation of tkinter. I have version 2.7.11. I entered the `pip install tkinter` on dos but it shows the following message:

> collecting tkinter
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions:)
>   No matching distribution found for tkinter

I have successfully installed flask with the same procedure, but for tkinter it is showing problem. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Where did you get Python? The standard distribution includes Tcl and Tkinter.

Comment: Does 'on dos' mean Windows?  If you want answers, answer Tigerhawk's question.

Comment: by Dos i mean command line of windows. I already got the answer but writing this down just in case someone ponders upon this question in the future.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Tkinter library comes in default with every Python installation

Try this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Comment: oh yes i got that , i think i got stuck at the caps , i used `import tkinter `     rather than `import Tkinter  ` i dint thought that this issue may arise , well thanks for the answer !

Comment: @Syed `tkinter` will be correct when you use 3.x. The names of submodules also change.  `TkFont` becomes `tkinter.font`.  And so on.

Comment: @Prabhakar , got that !

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy: I am using 3.6 and <code>import tkinter</code> does not work. And when trying <code>pip install tkinter</code>, I get 'No matching distribution' also.

Comment: I get the same @SyedHissaan problem with "pip install Tkinter". The system returns an error message when I run on jupyter `import Tkinter as tk` ---> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'`

Comment: If you have python 2.x and 3.x installed on your machine as me, make sure you use `python3 XXX.py` instead of `python XXX.py` to run this script.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

Answer (score 43):

You should install

```
apt-get install python-tk
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: Depends on what OS is being used.

Comment: In my case it was `apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: if not root user then sudo apt-get install python3-tk

Comment: Yes  but not for windows...

Answer (score 8):

This will work for tkinter installment

```
pip install tk
python -m pip install tk
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The tk package provides something else - "TensorKit is a deep learning helper between Python and C++."
Source: https://pypi.org/project/tk/

Answer (score 3):

Follow this guide to install "tkinter". However now with Python version 3.1 onwards, it is part of the standard python distribution.

You can also install it using `sudo apt-get install python3-tk-dbg`, if you are in virtualenv. (Same can be done for normal installation, not just virtualenv)

Answer (score 3):

**Windows**

**You may not have ticked tkinter during installation.**

- Download the latest version of python from python.org
- Run the installer
- Click modify
- Select the Tk checkbox (and anything else you want)
- And continue through the installation.

Done.

Answer (score 2):

to find your package run:

> sudo yum search python|grep tk

mine was:

> yum install python3-tkinter.x86_64

Answer (score 2):

On a MacBook use brew install python-tk

The error will be sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this on Amazon Linux 2 with `python2.7` by running this `sudo yum install python-tools -y` command.

Comment: this did not work for me on CentOS 7 with python3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

I had to install python3-tk manually before it worked (via apt-get)

Answer (score 0):

the below answer in for Windows:

after installing Tk in your windows machine by following the instructions mentioned in the following link (https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installwin), import tkinter as tk (for python3) or import Tkinter as tk (for python2). FYI - 'Tkinter' has been renamed as 'tkinter' in python3. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

pip shown 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `python--tkinter` (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for `python--tkinter`
You are using `pip version 10.0.1`, however `version 19.0.3` is available.
You should consider upgrading via the `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` command.

Comment: you can't install tkinter with pip

Answer (score 0):

`import Tkinter as tk`

Notice the `T`. This was changed in python 3.x

Comment: This answer is the same as the one of Hissaan Ali Shah.

Answer (score 0):

I was running a Flask application in the almaLinux docker image and my fix for this was.

```
yum install python39* -y 
#Be aware this will install Everything including things you don't need.
```

So this could be a simply case of you need to install the right package for the version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

T of Tkinter should be lowercase

Not

```
 import Tkinter as tk
```

Use as folow:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

or

```
from tkinter import * 
not : from Tkinter import *
```

Answer (score -1):

just go on cmd and type `pip intall Tk interface`,
i thinks this is the full true name of tkinter module