# tkinter no module found windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pip

I am trying to run this code

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk() 
w = Canvas(master, width=40, height=60) 
w.pack() 
canvas_height=20
canvas_width=200
y = int(canvas_height / 2) 
w.create_line(0, y, canvas_width, y ) 
mainloop()
```

and I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Since tkinter is already present in python, I checked in the  `C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages` to see if tkinter is already present but its not there, also I tried the following

> Running python -m tkinter from the command line should open a window
>   demonstrating a simple Tk interface, letting you know that tkinter is
>   properly installed on your system, and also showing what version of
>   Tcl/Tk is installed, so you can read the Tcl/Tk documentation specific
>   to that version

as mentioned on [tkinter — Python interface to Tcl/Tk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

I tried to [install](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) the `tkinter` using `pip3 install tk` , and I got `Requirement already satisfied: tk in c:\python38\Lib\site-packages (0.1.0)`

But when I run the code again I get the error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)                            ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

My python version is **Python 3.8.0** and pip version is **pip 19.3.1**

I have referred [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928710/why-is-there-no-tkinter-distribution-found) but no success.

Where am I going wrong? Please help

Comment: you can't install tkinter with pip.

Comment: What is the output of this, when placed before the import? `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: @Bryan Oakley you want me to run that on the cmd???

Comment: @SachinYadav: ***"run that on the cmd?"***: Edit your code and place it befor `from tkinter import *` then run it.

Answer (score 0):

**You may not have ticked tkinter during installation.**

- Download the latest version of python from python.org
- Run the installer
- Click modify
- Select the Tk checkbox (and anything else you want)
- And continue through the installation.

Done.