# How to resolve python dependency version

Tags: python, pip

I tried running a python script which uses matplotlib. I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q3.py", line 6, in <module>
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
  File "/home/raj/raj/venvs/notes-bash-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1162, in use
    plt.switch_backend(name)
  File "/home/raj/raj/venvs/notes-bash-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 276, in switch_backend
    class backend_mod(matplotlib.backend_bases._Backend):
  File "/home/raj/raj/venvs/notes-bash-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 277, in backend_mod
    locals().update(vars(importlib.import_module(backend_name)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/raj/raj/venvs/notes-bash-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "/home/raj/raj/venvs/notes-bash-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

So I tried installing `tkinter`:

```
$ pip3 install tkinter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

What cound be wrong? For the same script, I installed numpy, pandas and matplotlib using command like `pip3 install numpy`. I am on python 3.8.2 and pip-20.2.3. Also I am on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2.

Comment: [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) is an inbuilt library

Comment: then what could be the problem? I just installed it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523352/6357916). Also just to update, I am on ubuntu 20.04 on WSL if it matters.

Comment: Are you using `pyinstaller`?

Comment: @CoolCloud doing `pip install`. Did come across pyinstaller earlier. Whats upp with it? Will it resolve my issue?

Comment: Im not sure though, why not try?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install dependencies for Tkinter systemwide?:

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

Comment: I just ran `apt-get install python-tk`  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523352/6357916). Should I try your command too?

Comment: @anir, `python-tk` maybe not the same as `python3-tk`(different python versions)

Comment: ok ended up getting `File "/home/raj/raj/venvs/notes-bash-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 284, in switch_backend
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running`

Answer (score 0):

You may resolve it by using this command OS-wide:

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

Check it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: I just ran `apt-get install python-tk`  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523352/6357916). Should I try your command (`python3-tk`) too?

Comment: `python-tk` works for Python2, while `python3-tk` works for Python3 as far as I know.

Comment: ok ended up getting `File "/home/raj/raj/venvs/notes-bash-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 284, in switch_backend
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running`

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57636427/5790653