# tkinter not working in python 3(in linux)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter

Error Message

```
import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

from tkinter import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried `pip install tkinter` but then this error comes up

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

Comment: [Why is there no tkinter distribution found?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523352/5956174)

Comment: have your tried "pip3 install tkinter"

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: You need to install system package using the package manager of your Linux, for example, `sudo apt-get python3-tk` in Debian based Linux.

Comment: pip3 install tkinter is having the same error as pip install tkinter

Comment: i am running python 3.9.1

Comment: I am using manjaro , python3-tk is not found using pacman